# NAnt get task - the remote certificate is invalid according to validation procedure

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, nant

I'm using NAnt to download a file from a server with a self-signed certificate and it's giving me an error stating 'the remote certificate is invalid according to validation procedure'.

I've imported the certificate (according to this [procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx#BKMK_addlocal)) to the machine executing the script so I know it's loaded, but I'm still getting the error.

Can anyone offer suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem (may not be applicable to your environment) was that I had referenced the server by it's IP address in my NAnt script, but the server's self-signed certificate referenced the server hostname.

When I tweaked my NAnt property for the URL to use the hostname rather than the IP address, it was able to find the applicable certificate and download the file.